# Assigning values to 2D array of pointers in Arduino

Tags: c++, arrays, arduino

I'm working on an arduino project and I've been struggling to find a way how to assign values to 2D array of pointers (if im correct).
I have this array `char* numbers[3][4];`
I want it to be 4 characters long - for 4 numbers (like a code). **But please note that I cannot change the declaration, only change the number of strings.**
I have tried assigning the values with strcpy:

```
strcpy(*numbers[0], "1234");
strcpy(*numbers[1], "5678");
strcpy(*numbers[2], "9012");
```

After assigning the values, the array should be used as a parameter of a function
`void render_numbers(char** numbers, const int index);`
which basically prints the 4-digit code on Arduino Serial at the given index.
So I called the function:

```
render_numbers(*numbers, 2);
```

My function:

```
void render_numbers(char** numbers, const int index){
 Serial.println(numbers[index]);
}
```

So it passes the compiler, but in Serial it only prints unreadable characters (squares, question marks, etc.)

Comment: If your array is 4 chars long, that means you only have 3 chars to work with. 1 needs to be the null terminator for cstrings.

Comment: Why are you using plain C arrays and C strings for this? Have you installed the Arduino STL?

Comment: @TedLyngmo No I have not, but it wasn't mentioned in the task. So it shouldn't be used and it should be done this "plain C" way.

Comment: Wouldn't tagging it C be more appropriate if you want C answers?

Comment: the decleration is for 3x4 = 12 char pointers and this array does not have a place to store chars in it. it is for pointers so you can't use strcpy on it

Answer (score 0):

to assign array of strings in c do the following:

```
const char* numbers[]={"1234","5678","9012"};
```

to declare array of strings each has 4 chars:

```
char numbers[3][4];
```

so 
numbers[1] ==> char* // pointer to first char
numbers[1][2] ==> char // the char value

to Declare 2D array of pointers

```
const char* numbers[][] = {{"1234","5678"},{"1234","1111"}};
```

NOTE: strcpy copys source string to destination including null term char so it require 5 chars to store 4.

```
char numbers[3][5];
strcpy(numbers[1],"1234");
Serial.println(numbers[1]);
```

Comment: for what reason?

Comment: It cannot be const.

Comment: Whay it can't be const?